# How to get total amount of sales out of the 5 top-selling products?

Tags: sql

Table structure:

```
Category
CategoryID|CategoryCode|CategoryName

SubCategory
SubCategoryID|CategoryCode|SubCategoryCode|SubCategoryName

Products
ProductID|CategoryCode|SubCategoryCode|SKU|ProductName|UnitPrice

Orders
OrderID|OrderCode|CustomerCode|EmployeeCode|PurchaseDateTime

Order_Details
OrderDetailID|OrderCode|SKU|Quantity|Price|NetSales
```

Example

```
CategoryCode - 'S'

SubCategoryCode - '08'

SKU - '003'
```

The product is identified by S08003 and so on so forth

I would like to get the top amount of sales out of the 5 top-selling products identified by this combined product key... Notice that the SKU in the order_details table has already been compiled .

Comment: Post the code which you have tried so far

Comment: select sum(COALESCE(od.NetSales, 0)) As Total 
       from order_details od

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a sub-select.

```
SELECT Order_Details.SKU,
SUM(Order_Details.Quantity * Order_Details.Price) AS Total_Revenue
FROM Order_Details
WHERE Order_Details.SKU IN
 (SELECT X.SKU FROM Order_Details AS X
  ORDER BY SUM(X.Quantity) DESC
  GROUP BY X.SKU LIMIT 5)
GROUP BY Order_Details.SKU;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I was wondering how I can limit this query to the top 5 products. I am using Derby, I can't make use of the clause "LIMIT" since it is not available

Comment: Derby 1.5 has a strange LIMIT syntax, something like FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Okay, I found it. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html